# Are there any scenarios where putting const on a variable more than once would be useful?

Tags: c, constants

Normally in C if I want to declare a constant string I do this:

```
const char *p = "Friend";
```

However, if I really want to get the point across, I can do this:

```
const const const const const const const const const const const const const
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const 
const const const const const const const const const const const const const
const char *p = "Friend";
```

Are there any reasons why this may be useful?
Are there any scenarios where it is useful?

Comment: It literally does nothing. You can't make a constant more constant. Not sure why they let this slide, but since it really does nothing...

Comment: @Frontear They let it slide because, well, why bother with it. It's useless, but also harmless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C11 [§6.7.3 Type qualifiers ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p5) says:

> If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same *specifier-qualifier-list*, either directly or via one or more typedefs, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.

So the standard says "it is permitted, but pointless".  Saying the same thing many times doesn't make it any truer, propaganda notwithstanding.

Comment: (not an add-on to the question) Do you have any idea why they chose to do this?

Comment: I don't know why, but I think the 'via typedefs' part is probably the main reason.

Comment: Hmmm; I searched for _'specifier-qualifier-list'_ and it shows up in [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1) and [§6.7.7 Type names](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.7), but the syntax for _declaration specifiers_ in [§6.7 Declarations ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p1) doesn't preclude repeated type qualifiers, but neither does it say in words of 3 syllables or less what happens if they are repeated.  I think what §6.7.3¶5 says would be expected, though.

Comment: @jl2210: because writing the grammar to forbid it is too annoying. And it does no harm.